# Is it possible for electroweak monopoles to catalyze electroweak burning?

Tags: electroweak, magnetic-monopoles

Given that both electroweak monopoles and the Sphaleron process involve the non-trivial aspects of electroweak interactions, I am curious about whether there is theoretical or experimental evidence to support the idea that electroweak monopoles might influence the occurrence of Sphaleron processes.